# How to customize datetimebox in jquery easyui not to display seconds and set default time to 12:00 am?

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

How to customize datetimebox in jquery easyui not to display seconds and set default time to   12:00 am?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can refer to:
http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datetimebox.php
in order to find info about datetimebox

I have created a jsFiddle for you that solves your problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/gAcRM/

The property that hides the seconds is: `showSeconds: false`

Comment: Thanks for you time. But I am involved in an old project which uses jquery easyui version 1.2.6; showSeconds:false doesn't seem to workout on my case. Thanks anyway for the fiddle link.Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

according to [nickey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3414905/nickey) answer, you can try to add this function and comment the showSeconds

```
function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
 }

$.fn.datetimebox.defaults.formatter = function(date){
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  var m = date.getMonth()+1;
  var d = date.getDate();
  var h = date.getHours();
  var mm = addZero(date.getMinutes());
  return m+'/'+d+'/'+y+' '+h+':'+mm;
}
```

you can try the code at http://jsfiddle.net/kapasaja/v7xeyhke/

hope this can help you and let me know if it's not working for you